# How can I keep record of individual client traffic and speed using Netty?

Tags: java, networking, netty, nio

I'm implementing an HTTP server and I have a task to track individual clients' connections and gather the information about amount of bytes they sent and received from server, as well as an average connection speed. The server is implemented using an implementation of `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` where I handle `HttpRequest`s and manage `HttpResponse`s. I understand that I should add another handler (to the front of the pipeline?) to track incoming and outgoing connections, but I can't come to a solution about handling individual connections.

Comment: IMHO, connection speed should be measured on the client side.

Comment: @IgorAlelekov, I can't disagree with you, but I'd also like to know if there still is a chance of implementing it as described.

Comment: In order to measure speed you need to measure a response time. Only clint knows when request was sent and response got. But you can measure how many bytes processed in second.

Comment: As an example you can take a look at Netty's ChannelTrafficShapingHandler

Comment: @IgorAlelekov, could you please help with counting bytes sent/received to/from just one client?

Comment: You could modify ChannelTrafficShapingHandler which already does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify for your needs ChannelTrafficShapingHandler which already does it.

Comment: By the way, what is the most convenient way to pass some information from handler to the next one in pipeline? Or should I make this a separate question?

Comment: You can attach any object to the channel. Or you can pass info with an object in the message.

Comment: You can also use the `userEventTriggered` event.